# Perl file reading

Tags: perl, file, cgi

I am learning perl/CGI right now and trying to figure out how to read files in perl. I got my program to read each line into new variable.

Now I want my program to read first line into a variable $first_line and rest of the file to be stored into another variable $rest. How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $first_line = <$file_handle>;

# read rest of the file only if first line was read
my $rest = defined($first_line) && do {
  # input record separator set to undef (slurp mode)
  local $/;
  <$file_handle>;
};
```